# Nenhum dispositivo aparece para o "run" do AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio

Estava tudo normal até que fui montar um emulador com a api 21, durante o processo deu erro de disco sem espaço, meu AndroidStudio estava numa partição do hd com pouco espaço, apos o erro o ele começou um processo de indexing, e ficou nisso durante quase meia hora até que eu resolvi fecha-lo e abri-lo novamente, daí quando clico em "run" nem os emuladores aparecem nem meu celular conectado.

Eu já tentei:

- Testar com dois celulares diferentes.
- Montar uma nova imagem do emular com outra versão do android.
- Iniciar o emulador pelo AVD Manager, ele inicia os já criados mas quando clico em "run" não aparece nada.
- Já reinstalei o AndroidStudio.
- já o instalei em outro lugar e iniciei o novo e mesmo assim não aparece nada e nem dá nenhum erro.

Ele fica apenas assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no processo do adb.exe que estava escutado porém sem fazer nada, para resolver foi simples, só abrir o gerenciar de tarefas e finalizar o processo, então voltar no Android Studio e tentar executar novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar voltar o android studio as configurações iniciais.

Vá a pasta de usuário

```
C:\Users\Seu_usuario
```

Nesta página, deve ter uma pasta com o nome de `.AndroidStudio` com sua versão atribuída ao nome da pasta.

Faça um backup desta pasta, e depois apague ela, isso removerar suas configurações.

Caso já tenha tentado isso, tente reinstalar as api.
Vá em `Default Settings`

Em SDK Plataforms, instale as versões, reinstale as API, e tente outras novas.
Depois, vá em *SDK Tools*, vá em `Show Package Details` e certifique-se de marcar as `Android SDK Build-Tools` nas versões que você escolheu antes.